# delphi EmbeddedWB iframe height issue

Tags: delphi, iframe, height

i have few webpages in MySQL database, that I want to show as "slideshow" on my Delphi (7) form.
I am trying to use EmbeddedWebBrowser for it, and generating my HTML file dynamically, using `iframe` tags - for showing more than 1 webpage at the moment.

the problem is, when i load this html file into EmbeddedWB, the height is only around 150px, however in IE, FF, chrome looks OK.

My Delphi code:

```
embeddedwb1.LoadFromFile('mypage.html');
```

any suggestions?

PS: the webpages from my collection aren't from same domain.

how to reproduce:
Place an Embeddedwebbrowser component to form, set

```
RegisterAsBrowser
```

parameter to

```
True
```

, for "silent" mode i added this Event to EmbeddedWebBrowser:

```
procedure TForm1.EmbeddedWB1ScriptError(Sender: TObject; ErrorLine, ErrorCharacter, ErrorCode, ErrorMessage, ErrorUrl: String; var ContinueScript, Showdialog: Boolean); 
    begin 
    continuescript:=true;
    showdialog:=false; 
    end;
```

then I generated with a simple for... loop html code shown above.. If mypage website in  has "child" iframe, it's not showing correctly the child iframe height (from another domain).. 
If this ads.html file (generated by this simple delphi app) is opened in normal IE (11) , it showing child iframe correctly... I tried to change embeddedwebbrowser parameters (there are a lot of them) , but without success.. Sorry for this "full working example" - i need to learn how to write with better quality, but 1) my english is not good 2) i am new here, must learn a lot :) but this problem is almost critical, i must solve it till wednesday
i placed one button to form1 , the form doing the following:

embeddedwb1.LoadFromFile('mypage.html');

example of 'mypage.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11"></head>
<body>
<iframe style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%" src="http://www.expresspaid.net/?x=ptcview&amp;view=bHNETmxjTXd1ck4wQWxYWmx6YWRkS0xSWGVZSklWSlJ3aWVOdzVkOXNhND0,">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

## **UPDATE**

AFTER ONE WEEK OF GOOGLING I FIXED THIS PROBLEM! :)

the solution was:

when i generated .html file from Delphi  (wrote whole code dynamically to textfile and then opened in EmbeddedWB)
I wrote iframe tag like this:

```
htmlpage:=htmlpage+`'<iframe width="100%" height="800" src="'+mypagestring+'"></iframe>'+#13+#10;
```

but it was not good..

my new and working html  tag:

```
htmlpage:=htmlpage+'<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" width="100%" height="800" src="+mypagestring+"></iframe>'+#13+#10;
```

as You see, usage of `sandbox` in parent iframe helped me to show full child iframe, not only a piece of that :)

Comment: Your meta tag is probably not working because it is in the body section, not in the head section...

Comment: thanks, already fixed, but result is the same.  I found hundreds of StackOverflow questions about this problem, but nothing helped. The source of problem is in the external iframe in webpage i am trying to load

Comment: It is possible that you need to implement the OnResizexxx events... Please include a [full working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: No problem Ian, can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37516763/edit) your question instead of posting code in the comments. Try to make a minimal example (also the  html) so we can reproduce the problem easily..

Comment: @whosrdaddy thanks for advice, i changed the text of my question, i hope its clear :)